# What unit is used in python’s resource RLIMIT_FSIZE setting

Tags: python, ulimit, setrlimit

According to [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html#resource-limits), with Python you can set the file size limit with:

```
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_FSIZE,(fileseeklimit,fileseeklimit))
```

but it is not clear what the unit is here.

The Bash builtin `ulimit` uses kilobytes for everything.

Answer (score 2):

The `RLIMIT_FSIZE` here is a number of bytes.

A comment in the header file where that enum is defined says this:

```
/* Largest file that can be created, in bytes.  */
```